# Jquery tablesorter failing on basic page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tablesorter

I have the code below, I have been fighting to get this to work, to the point where I copied the example from the tablesorter website.  Can anyone help me with what I'm doing wrong?  I've followed tutorial videos http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-wAWfPVXlME

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Test Table</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="testTable.css">
    <script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="jquery.tablesorter.pager.js" type="text/javascript" ></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() 
            {
                $("#myTable").tablesorter();
            }
        );
    </script>



    </head>

    <body>
        <h4>Table Testing</h4>

        <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
            <thead> 
                <tr> 
                    <th>Last Name</th> 
                    <th>First Name</th> 
                    <th>Email</th> 
                    <th>Due</th> 
                    <th>Web Site</th> 
                </tr> 
            </thead> 
            <tbody> 
                <tr> 
                    <td>Smith</td> 
                    <td>John</td> 
                    <td>jsmith@gmail.com</td> 
                    <td>$50.00</td> 
                    <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td>Bach</td> 
                    <td>Frank</td> 
                    <td>fbach@yahoo.com</td> 
                    <td>$50.00</td> 
                    <td>http://www.frank.com</td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td>Doe</td> 
                    <td>Jason</td> 
                    <td>jdoe@hotmail.com</td> 
                    <td>$100.00</td> 
                    <td>http://www.jdoe.com</td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td>Conway</td> 
                    <td>Tim</td> 
                    <td>tconway@earthlink.net</td> 
                    <td>$50.00</td> 
                    <td>http://www.timconway.com</td> 
                </tr> 
            </tbody> 
        </table> 

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like you're only loading the pager `jquery.tablesorter.pager.js` and not the tablesorter core.

Comment: Do you get any errors? You probably see an undefined function if Mottie is correct. A good way to start is to debug your js errors...

Comment: I am using notepad++ and not receiving any errors.  When I load the page in any browser it displays an unstyled html table.

Comment: Hey, just used the core versus the pager.  That worked perfectly, thanks Mottie and jtheman!

    <script src="jquery.tablesorter.pager.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

changed to:

   <script src="jquery.tablesorter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you load the tablesorter core:

```
<script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> 
<script src="jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"></script>
```

And since it looks like you're using HTML5, the `type="text/javascript"` isn't needed inside the script tag.

Comment: Worked great, I left a comment above.  Thanks for the help, saved me hours or trying to hard code everything.